# Issues Reloading/Redeploying JPA App in Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, deployment, glassfish-4

As per my recent questions, we are having issues deploying multiple app wars to the same Glassfish4 server that include an JPA/EJB jar file.  Currently, we are including the jar file in each war.

We have written a simple test servlet that will insert records into the database.  We can reload, redeploy (same war) and undeploy/deploy (same war) that app and everytime the JPA stuff works without error/restarting the server.

We have another app that is a RESTFul service (Jersey) that if we reload, we get this exception when accessing the JPA service bean:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
```

If we redeploy the app (with same war) and try to access the service beans, we get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Change ID=ABCD is not a known entity type.
```

where "ABCD" is the value being passed to a Batch entity's setChangeId() method.

I found this Glassfish bug (which is supposed to be fixed in v4 but doesn't appear to be) https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17295 which states that a workaround is to do a full undeploy/deploy.  When that is done we get same IllegalArgumentException.

In all these error cases, the server must be restarted in order for the app to work again

There must be something different between the test app that doesn't have issues with reloads/redeployments and the other one, but I can't find it.  Both apps include the same EJB/JPA jar file.  Both apps inject the service bean like this:

```
@EJB
private transient DataService dataService;
```

We inject the EntityManager in the JPA service bean like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "data")
private EntityManager em;
```

What else should I be looking at for a difference?

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="data" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/data</jta-data-source>            
        <properties>
            <!-- disable ddl generation -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="NONE"/>

            <!-- log sqls executed in server.log -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />

            <!-- Instruct EclipseLink to not log execeptions it throws. Lets the application  decide about it -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false" />
        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>         
</persistence>
```

**Update**

I came across a webpage that implied that there was a bug in the admin console app for redploying apps and that using the asadmin CLI should work.  So, I tried deploying/undeploying that way, but still had the same errors.

Comment: Are you manually accessing an `EntityManagerFactory` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No. In our JPA service bean, we inject the EntityManger. Updated question with code.

Comment: Please add your `persistence.xml` to the question.

Comment: Added.  I don't think that should be part of the issue though. I would expect problems with both apps if it were...

Comment: Why are you using persistence version 1.0? Maybe this makes a difference?

Comment: Probably a copy/paste issue. I updated to 2.0 but am still experiencing the same issues.  We have other Java6 apps deployed in GF3.1 that work without problem.  However, this app with problems is our first Jersey app that uses JPA. I would think that shouldn't be a problem, but it is the biggest difference between it and the one that works (simple servlet).